# Mockito: Fake first call, do nothing for the rest

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, spy

Suppose I have an object of type `MyType`, that has a function called `func()` that returns a `String`. For our use case, assume we have an instance of `MyType`, called `myType`, through which we call `func()` five times:

```
MyType myType = new MyType();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   String retVal = myType.func(...)
}
```

If I wanted to mock `MyType::func()` every single one of these iterations, I could have done something like this, because the `when()` method allows chaining.

```
when(myType.func()).thenReturn("one").thenReturn("two").thenReturn("three").thenReturn("four").thenReturn("five");
```

But what if I wanted to only mock the first call, and simply spy (i.e do nothing) for the rest? I can't chain `doNothing()` calls...

Comment: Try to chain `.thenCallRealMethod()`.

Comment: See, the thing is that I *don't* want that to happen. I need the method to NOT be called.

Comment: It's in a loop - it has to return something - return null or an empty string?